If/Then Python Script for SharePoint
We have thousands of construction blueprints in PDF format, many go back decades. Many blueprints are duplicates created accidentally because we never established a proper naming procedure. So a project titled 'H.C. 1598' may have a duplicate titled 'HC 1598', or 'HC1598' or 'H.C.1598'.
We want to delete all the copies except the correct one, which would be 'HC 1598' (no periods and a space between HC and the project number).
I am looking for a python script to run in SharePoint to do this, but I cannot figure out:

how to write the script, and

how to run the script in a folder in SharePoint?


If anyone could assist it would be greatly appreciated.
